# Firebase authentication change listener is never triggered in nativescript-angular app

Tags: nativescript-angular, nativescript-firebase

I using nativescript firebase (`@nativescript/firebase`) plugin version 11.1.3 in my project. I want to check if the user is logged in at the start of the application and redirect to 'items page' or login accordingly. Therefore, I've included `onAuthStateChanged` option inside `firebase.init` which is called inside `ngInit` of AppComponent:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {firebase} from "@nativescript/firebase";
import {BackendService} from "./shared/services/backend.service";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {

        firebase.init({
            // -- persist: true,

            onAuthStateChanged: (data: any) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
                if (data.loggedIn) {
                    BackendService.token = data.user.uid;

                } else {
                    BackendService.token = "";
                }
            }
        }).then(
            () => {
                console.log("firebase.init done");
            },
            error => {
                console.log(`firebase.init error: ${error}`);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

`BackendService` is responsible for saving token to application settings. `onLogin()` method below resides in login component which authenticate and redirect user to items views:

```
onLogin(): void {

        this.isAuthenticating = true;

        this.firebaseService.login(this.user)
            .then(result => {
                this.isAuthenticating = false;
                this.routerEx.navigate(["/items"], {clearHistory: true});
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.isAuthenticating = false;
                alert((error.split(':')[1]))
            });
    }
```

I have an `authentication gaurd` on items component which redirect users back to login component if 'token' (UID currently) is not set.

```
    canActivate() {
        if (BackendService.isLoggedIn()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.routerEx.navigate(["/login"]);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

From the console logs, it clearly shows that am able to login successfully but the app remains on login screen. In fact it redirect to `items` and auth guard redirect it back to login screen since `onAuthStateChanged` was not trigged and `token` was not set.

I've tried `firebase.addAuthStateListener(listener)` with `onAuthStateChanged` outside `firebase.init` and still doing the same thing. Please bear with me folks if you think my question is too obvious as I am a newbie to nativescript and still learning most of the concept.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Any success with it?